# Suitable way for exercising upper body

Tags: home-exercise, upper-body-workout, timing

I'm currently using 30 day fitness challenge app, Full-body workout medium plan 2, it's great and working fine but I feel that **it's only exercising my lower body**. I want to exercise my upper body (arm and chest).

Should I make it one day for upper body and one for lower body ? or how should I organize that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest [Phrak's Greyskull LP](https://forum.bodybuilding.com/showthread.php?t=163054151&page=1).
It is a variant of Starting Strength (SS) with more emphasis on upper body and aesthetics than SS. You train the whole body 3 days a week.

If you want to do a upper/lower split you should train at least 4 days a week.
Splits are more for bodybuilders who do not mind spending a lot of time in the gym.

You can do the much easier goblet squats instead of back squats the first months.

Be careful with the deadlift. It is not difficult, but if you do it wrong you can really hurt your back (herniated disk).
Watch videos carefully and film your self to make sure you are doing it right.

When doing the benchpress make sure your shoulder blades stay pinned to the bench in a pulled together and down position. Do not lift with your shoulders.

Answer (score 0):

What's your routine like currently? I can't comment for sure but usually the weakest/least developed part of the body or the muscle being used the most feels the burn. So that means in this routine you're either using bad form to compensate for your weaker upper body, thereby using more lower body muscles or you're upper body can handle this routine and it's the lower body that feels the burn more so.

I would suggest making sure your form is on point, and if so, definitely add an upper body day. This is the most general advice I can give until I get a more specific outline of the routine you follow from you.

Answer (score 0):

For chest, triceps and shoulders:

- Pike pushups
- Wide grip pushups
- Close grip pushups

For back and biceps:

- Pullups
- Chinups
- Body rows

Abs:

- Hanging / Lying leg raise
- Alternating jack knife
- Lying bicycles

Lower Back:

- Reverse plank
- Superman

Select the exercise according to your fitness level and decide a set/rep range (e.g.  5*5, 4*6, 3*8, 2*12 meaning sets* reps)

You can do total body workout 3-4 times a week (1 rest day in between) or upper body, lower body alternating without rest days

Please check the form for exercise on the Internet, I prefer [Calisthenicsmovements](https://www.youtube.com/user/Calisthenicmovement) on YouTube